# View border with arrow

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am currently designing an iPad application with a number of text fields, when I click these text fields I want a little view to popup (these will contain table views with options etc) all this is working perfectly. However, I want to put an arrow to show which text field the user is entering.

Best example is on iPad Safari, when you hit search it brings up a view with an arrow on the top. I have seen these in loads of apps and want to do the same.

Any ideas how I go about this?

Comment: Are you looking for UIPopoverController? See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/Popovers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH5-SW1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a popoverController. Good starter: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3tW4h95-Cw&list=PL1824275972079B55.

Instead of subclass a viewcontroller, subclass tableviewcontroller. Pass the tableviewcontroller to initWithContentViewController/

Code Example:

```
UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:yourtableviewcontroller];
[pop setDelegate:self];
[pop presentPopoverFromRect:popbutton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Change the direction depending on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a view (one of the text fields) and viewController, which you want to present. This code will present a popover with arrow pointing on the middle of your view.
You can use any combination of UIPopoverArrowDirection (for instance UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown). In this example popover will show the similar way it happens in Safari.

Use this code if you want your popover to appear with arrow pointing in the middle of the view:

```
UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.frame) - 1, CGRectGetMidY(view.frame) - 1, 1, 1);
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:animated];
```

Or use this code if you want your popover to appear with arrow pointing anywhere in the view:

```
UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:view.frame inView:view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:animated];
```